# How to find duplicated values in first column with different values in second column in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I need the formula to help me find data like the red ones in this example. Is it possible without any extra tools?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is posible to do it with macro or with two added column:
first one C is textsplit A and B for counting unique items

```
=CONCATENATE(A2,":",B2)
```

next is for D column, couting a and compare if it is the same as C:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$9,A2)=COUNTIF(C$2:C$9,C2),,1)
```

then you can set filter or colours if in D is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Conditional Formatting Rules:

1. Select your Data (you can do it for each column or all together)
2. Conditional Formatting
3. New Rule
4. Use a formula to determine which cells to Format
5. Format Values where this formula is True
6. In the box write :

   =COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$12,$B2,$A$2:$A$12,$A2)=1
7. Format as you like
8. OK